# ¿Como cambio el idioma del plugin "momentjs"?

Tags: momentjs

He intentado de mil maneras que he visto en SOEn, pero ninguna me sirve.

Aca un ejemplo de lo que intento hacer:

```js
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      console.log(moment(new Date('2017-03-16')).format('dddd MMMM D'));
    });
```

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/locale/es.js"></script>
```

Acá funciona perfectamente, pero en mi sistema NO, ¿Por que pasara eso? Estoy trabajando con los mismos `cdn` que coloco en el ejemplo.

Comment: has intentado de esta forma `moment.lang("es").format('LLL');`

Comment: sip, de hecho me dice que de esa forma esta obsoleta.

Comment: Ya dame un momento, encontré la forma en que lo hacia yo, déjame lo busco bien y te lo paso

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales hermano, ya encontre mi error, en algun momento en mi proyecto me equivoque y copie la libreria al final, es decir, llamaba el archivo moment.js despues llamaba la traduccion, y al final de los scripts estaba de nuevo moment.js. Ya lo solucione. Borrare la pregunta ya que era un error mio.

Comment: puedes dejarla, de igual forma, sirve para que alguien mas pueda solucionar su problema, échale un ojo a lo que t deje seguro te servirá tambien

Comment: Es en realidad muy extraño lo que comentas. Llevo usando moment y nunca me ha pasado algo similar. De hecho, si vas al [sitio de moment](https://momentjs.com/) y seleccionas *Spanish* verás todo en Español.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

lo que se debe es especificar de manera clara, para que la librería, sepa que cuando utilices el `moment.lang("es")` o cualquier idioma pues te funcione donde sea.

```
moment.lang('es', {
  months: 'Enero_Febrero_Marzo_Abril_Mayo_Junio_Julio_Agosto_Septiembre_Octubre_Noviembre_Diciembre'.split('_'),
  monthsShort: 'Enero._Feb._Mar_Abr._May_Jun_Jul._Ago_Sept._Oct._Nov._Dec.'.split('_'),
  weekdays: 'Domingo_Lunes_Martes_Miercoles_Jueves_Viernes_Sabado'.split('_'),
  weekdaysShort: 'Dom._Lun._Mar._Mier._Jue._Vier._Sab.'.split('_'),
  weekdaysMin: 'Do_Lu_Ma_Mi_Ju_Vi_Sa'.split('_')
}
);
```

De esta forma puedes personalizar todos los formatos a como tu quieras, la función `split` que esta al final de cada linea indica que luego de cada **_** es un formato diferente.

Comment: interesante solución, gracias.

Answer (score 5):

Un poco tarde, pero el dia de hoy consulte esta información y la documentación.
Simplemente antes de la conversión importa el lenguaje:

```
moment.locale('es');
fecha_convertida = moment(fecha).format('llll');
```

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/

Answer (score 0):

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/

Primero tenes que importar el idioma que queres usar:

```
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/es';


moment.locale('es'); // aca ya esta en es
console.log('>>>>>>>', moment(test.date).format('MMMM')); //DICIEMBRE POR EJ
```

Comment: Esto es perfecto para typescript pero creo que la pregunta original era usando javascript.

Answer (score 0):

me funciona correctamente en Angular

```
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/es';
```

Comment: Para que esto sea útil a otros, incluye info como la versión de momentjs y de Angular que estás usando, por favor. Es muy posible que tú digas la verdad y los demás también, sólo que estén probando en versiones diferentes. Puedes [edit] tu respuesta.