# ¿Cómo pasar una fecha con la librería moment de javascript a formato en español?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

estoy haciendo un formato a una fecha con moment.js pero quiero que esta se obtenga en español, realizo lo siguiente como se haya en la documentación de la librería:

```
moment.locale('es');
fecha_con_formato = moment(fecha).format('LLL');
console.log(fecha_con_formato);
```

la variable **fecha** que le paso a moment la declaro anteriormente, en eso no hay problema alguno, el problema está en que no me pasa a español con **moment.locale('es')**,
me obtiene:

```
March 31, 2022 7:30 AM
```

Me pregunto si estoy definiendo el idioma correctamente o está mal, o se hace de otra manera.

Comment: ¿Podría ayudarte esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/56225/158433)?

Comment: Estoy trabajando con componentes de Vue js, la librería ya la instalé con npm, pero al momento de importar el lenguaje en donde regularmente importo las librerías me arroja error: **Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'moment' in**  y el error **Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'moment/locale/es'**. El lugar donde intento importar esa librería del idioma es inmediatamente después de abrir la etiqueta script que contiene un componente de vue

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Cambiar formato de fecha a español con Jquery y Moment](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/207409/cambiar-formato-de-fecha-a-espa%c3%b1ol-con-jquery-y-moment). ¿Incluiste la [librería local para español](https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js)? Si no la incluyes no podrás poner las fechas en español.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como cambio el idioma del plugin "momentjs"?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56219/como-cambio-el-idioma-del-plugin-momentjs)